# What is the meaning of e.fn in this code

Tags: javascript

I am looking at this javascript code from the [quojs](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) library:

```
(function() {
  var e;
  e = function() {
    var e, t, n;
    t = [];
    e = function(t, r) {
      var i;
      if (!t) {
        return n()
      } else if (e.toType(t) === "function") {
        return e(document).ready(t)
      } else {
        i = e.getDOMObject(t, r);
        return n(i, t)
      }
    };
    n = function(e, r) {
      e = e || t;
      e.__proto__ = n.prototype;
      e.selector = r || "";
      return e
    };
    e.extend = function(e) {
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1).forEach(function(t) {
        var n, r;
        r = [];
        for (n in t) {
          r.push(e[n] = t[n])
        }
        return r
      });
      return e
    };
    n.prototype = e.fn = {};
    return e
  }();
```

which comes before this:

```
(function () {
    (function (e) {
        var t, n, r, i, u, a;
        r = "parentNode";
        t = /^\.([\w-]+)$/;
        n = /^#[\w\d-]+$/;
        i = /^[\w-]+$/;
        e.query = function (e, r) {
            var u;
            r = r.trim();
            if (t.test(r)) {
                u = e.getElementsByClassName(r.replace(".", ""))
            } else if (i.test(r)) {
                u = e.getElementsByTagName(r)
            } else if (n.test(r) && e === document) {
                u = e.getElementById(r.replace("#", ""));
                if (!u) {
                    u = []
                }
            } else {
                u = e.querySelectorAll(r)
            }
            if (u.nodeType) {
                return [u]
            } else {
                return Array.prototype.slice.call(u)
            }
        };

        e.fn.find = function (t) {
```

I am trying to understand the meaning of e.fn.

I see that fn is not a [reserved word](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm). I think that e is just the name given to the event object passed as a parameter. So what is the meaning of e.fn? Is the code assuming that whatever is passed as e has a property called fn? Or is fn some kind of abbreviation that references the function?

Comment: Single-Letter Variable Names...YUCK!

Comment: @W.K.S: This is likely some library code from somewhere else that's been minified.

Comment: Open up the console in your debugger, stick a break point on that line and find out what e actually is. You've left out the code where `e` is passed to your function anyway, so nobody is going to be able to guess what it is.

Comment: `console.log(e); console.log(e.fn)` - it could mean anything really, depending on the library you are showing the code from. `fn` in jQuery for example is an alias for the `prototype` property.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is passed as e should have a property called fn.  I would search the rest of the code for "fn" and see what you come up with.